# how to append output documents fetched (-O) by wget under windows

Tags: windows, wget

I am running wget (under windows) in a loop, every 10 seconds, to test the communication to my arduino server.

Currently, the server response goes to a file which I rename per the current time hence, a new file is created every 10 secs:

loop core:

```
wget --user=UUU --password=PPPPP --append-output=wgetout22.txt --output-document=delme.html 192.168.1.123/light
ren delme.html delme%temps%.html
```

I would like all the consecutive responses to go to one single file.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get your post. Doesn't the command above work? If so, add your post the exact ouput generated by that, please.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which works ok
loop core

```
    wget --user=uuu --password=ppp --append-output=wgetout.txt --output-document=new.html 192.168.1.123/light
```

type new.html >> all.html